# Why are some of my region names in checkout garbled?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, country-regions

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 and venustheme
For some reason some of my region names in checkout are shown garbled. I uncommented these but no use
 AddDefaultCharset Off
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
It doesn't look like typical encoding issue, because not only the special characters are garbled,  so what is going on there?

[image: this is how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer -  something happened with database, probably some importing mistake or so. I took fresh version of magento and replaced my messed up tables with new and looks nice now.